# What is the difference between dataframe.iloc[:;:] and datafrane.iloc[:,:] .values

Tags: python

Pandas dataframe.iloc[].values nad dataframe.iloc[]

Answer (score 1):

dataframe.iloc[].values and [dataframe.iloc[]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) both provide integer-location based indexing for selection by position.  dataframe.iloc[].values returns a Numpy array while dataframe.iloc[] returns a data frame.  Printing dataframe.iloc[] will show the row and column headers while printing dataframe.iloc[].values will not.  Re-using an example from @jezael:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

print(df.iloc[:, :-1])
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  4  7  1  5
1  2  5  8  3  3
2  3  6  9  5  6

X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
print (X)
[[1 4 7 1 5]
 [2 5 8 3 3]
 [3 6 9 5 6]]

print(type(X))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```